# Convert IList<IList<object>> to List<List<object>> form

Tags: c#

In the following code response.Values returns IList>

```
 IList<IList<object>> values = response.Values;
```

I want to convert `values` to `List<List<object>>` form. I have already tried using the following statement

```
List<List<object>> values = response.Values as List<List<object>>
```

After using this  statement

`values = null`

but

`response.Values.Count = 82`

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Why not just work with `values` as `IList<IList<Object>>`? You'll still be using the same methods as with the concrete List type.

Comment: The question was not "Should I convert IList<IList<object>> to List<List<object>>". Maybe he is just curious. Maybe there's a method that only takes List<List<object>>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know *why* you want to do that, but one way would be this:

```
var result = values.Select(v => v.ToList()).ToList();
```

But this could be an expensive operation if the lists are big and I don't see any advantage in converting this. `IList<object>` provides the functionality you need.
The only reason I can think of is that you want to pass this to a method that expects `List<List<object>>` as parameter type.

[`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) is a linq extension for an enumeration of type `T` that returns a `List<T>` containing the elements of the enumeration (`T` is `object` in your example).

Comment: This has horrendoues performance. `Cast<T>()` is orders of magnitude faster as it doesn't need to iterate every sublist.

Comment: @InBetween There is no cast from `IList<object>` to `List<object>` if you don't know the underlying type or especially if the underlying type is _not_ a `List<object>`!

Comment: This compiles and runs just fine: `public static List<List<T>> MyCast<T>(this IList<IList<T>> target) => target.Cast<List<T>>().ToList();`. Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: @InBetween yes this compiles fine, but it does not run fine, especially if the lists are other classes than `List<object>` but implementing `IList<object>`

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. That's true. Ok, I'll clarify my answer to make that clear. Still, if you *do* know that the underlying type really is a `List` and you are simply trying to circumvent a signature problem (most probable case as you youself state in your answer), `Cast<T>()` is way faster.

Comment: According to VS, I am missing a directive to use the `select` method. What should I do? @rené-vogt

Comment: @KirtiDhwajSingh Add a `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reasonable performance the following way:

```
values.Cast<List<T>>().ToList();
```

This does does *not* iterate through all the elements of each `List<T>` as [René Vogt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008364/767890) answer proposes and the performance gain is quite noticable.

UPDATE. As René Vogt points out, this will fail if the underlying type of the `IList` typed objects are not `List`s but some other type implementing `IList`. In that case you are stuck with using `Select` and paying the performance penalty.

If you *do* know that the underlying type really is a `List` then by all means use `Cast` as its much faster.

Comment: This will not work if the `IList<object>` elements in `values` are not of type `List<object>`. I think it won't work even if they are.

Comment: Of course it wont work if you are trying to cast to something that it is not. And?

Comment: Where did OP specifiy that values really contains `List<object>` elements? He only states that `values` contains elements that implement `IList<object>`

Comment: @RenéVogt I wasn't understanding your comment correctly. I've clarified it in comments to your answer and will edit my anser accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create a List of List and then in a loop fill it. Something like this:

```
List<List<object>> list = new List<List<object>>();

foreach(IList<object> l in values){
    list.Add(new List<object>(l));
}
```

I have not test it but I think it should work